# enqueue style and script WordPress doesn't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, enqueue

I'm trying to enqueue javascript and css in WordPress. I have written the following code but it is not working and no style or css is being added to my theme.

```
function add_theme_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'cssdatepicker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/persian-datepicker.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jsdate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/persian-date.js', array ( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jsdatepicker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/persian-datepicker.js', array ( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

Comment: Try to replace from add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' ); to add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_theme_scripts' );

Comment: Did you check in developer console, if the scripts and styles are being loaded or not ? Also in wp_enqueue_script the version parameter must be string, i.e. '1.1' and not just 1.1

Comment: @Ravi Kumar I tried it, but it doesn't work, too.

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh yes, I've checked it. and they aren't being loaded.

Comment: You are checking in admin side or front end?

Comment: did you check console is there any error showing 404 or anything else

Comment: the odd thing is that when I changed the $handler, it works. for example I wrote wp_enqueue_script( 'persiandate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/persian-date.js', array ( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true);

Comment: okay, I got your error what happened actually. please use below code. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be added but it showing you cache version CSS and js which is blank maybe

```
function add_theme_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'cssdatepicker', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/persian-datepicker.css', array(), null, 'all');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jsdate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/persian-date.js', array ( 'jquery' ), null, true);
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jsdatepicker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/persian-datepicker.js', array ( 'jquery' ), null, true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

use this code to run updated js and CSS file ( non-cache )

- OR

it is already added to your site but the path is wrong so it will throw an error in console.

you can see in the console using the F12 key

please check and let me know what is your status.

- OR

**wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )**

if your $handle has already existed with other style or script so it will not be added to your theme or plugin so be careful about this and add the unique name of **$handle**

> Note :- Add Unique name of $handle or add your own prefix before name of
>   $handle like **custom_jquery** this is our custom **jquery** $handle name

Refrence site :- [WP Codex wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: put last parameter null to remove cache version of 1.1 file and run every time new file

Comment: Thanks, my problem was with the $handle. I changed it, and the files now are being added.

Comment: Your welcome dude. please upvote it if you got your hardest solution.

Comment: dev_ramiz_1707  :-)